# What word can express a (fictional) transformation of a physical object into its artistic representation?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I am looking for a word similar to, or perhaps a generalization of, *[petrification/petrify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrifaction_in_mythology_and_fiction)*.  Whereas petrification involves a transformation of a physical object into a statue, the idea I have in mind is a transformation of a physical object into a two-dimensional projection of itself.  Another similar word is made up within the video game *Luigi's Mansion*, in which physical ghosts are turned into paintings of themselves via the *Ghost Portrificationizer* machine, but neither portrificationization nor portrification are real words.

A word that applies broadly to any type of artistic representation would also work, but the word should suggest that the object gets consumed in the process of creating the art, unlike most or all art in the real world, which merely creates an artistic copy of the physical object.

Here are the thesaurus searches I've tried, with no helpful results:
https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/petrify
https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/petrified

Comment: You might find a term in Baudrillard or other postmodern theory.

Comment: If such a word exists the game writers might not have needed to invent *portrification*.

Comment: 'Projection' itself has closely allied senses.

Comment: @WeatherVane As reasonable as that sounds, further context might offer another explanation.  The term chosen was "Ghost Portrificationizer" rather than something like "Ghost Portrifier," and the machine is owned by a character with the mad scientist persona, suggesting that the aim was to make the name sound wacky instead of linguistically realistic.

Comment: Sorry about that slip, the question mentions *portrification*. I notice that *portrify* has already been coined as a trading name.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The issue is that an ordinary projection does not consume objects or transform them into an output representation.  The original objects are expected to continue to exist after the projection.

Comment: In a fictional setting (and process) as asked, you can use a fictional word.

Comment: Could you please explain why 'representation' , the word you yourself chose, is not exactly what you need?  Of course, there are other words/expressions, like 'physical embodiment', but 'representation'  or, to be quite complete, 'three-dimensional representation' should do the job.

Comment: @Tuffy Similarly to "projection," "representation" does not imply that the physical objects represented cease to exist as physical object, as a result of the representation being created.

Comment: The object was [captured](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capture).

Comment: @10478  Well, quite literally, 're-' means 'again' and so 'represent' is presenting the thing, whatever it is, again (in a different form), which could be a two-dimensional picture, a poetic description or a three-dimensional sculpture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no such actual action possible, you could consider some similar concepts from other fields. For example *reduce* or *reduction* as in [Dimensionality Reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction)

> Dimensionality reduction, or dimension reduction, is the transformation of data from a high-dimensional space into a low-dimensional space

Alternatively, you can use common words and specify the exact meaning in context:

- *Flatten*
- *Collapse*

Comment: *"As there is no such actual action possible,"* - Citation needed.

Comment: For turning a physical 3D object into a 2D one?

Comment: I think the onus is on nnnnnnnn to prove it is possible. Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence. (Regardless, even if it's possible, there may not be a word for it.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use **realise/realize, realisation/realization** in the sense of "to make real"

"The ghosts are realized as paintings."

OED

> I. To give real existence to something.
>
> **1.a.** transitive. **To make real or actual; to convert (something imagined, planned, etc.) into real existence or fact; to bring (a scheme, ambition, etc.) to fruition. Formerly also: †to show the reality or truth of (a statement) (obsolete). Frequently in passive.**
>
> 1957   A. E. Stevenson New Amer. III. ii. 104   *We cannot produce overnight an abundance of modern, well-lighted school buildings with plenty of capable and devoted teachers, where every child is free to realize his best self.*
>
> 2004   Manch. Evening News (Nexis) 17 Feb. (Business section) 14   *Our expansion plans couldn't be realised without more funding.*

And the common "He left home and realised his dreams."

Comment: The OP is asking about a process that starts with a physical object, not a ghost.

Comment: @nnnnnn I don't think so --*in which physical ghosts are turned into paintings of themselves* ghosts are immaterial (regardless of what the OP says, you can't have a "physical" ghost), paintings are material.

Comment: The question says, "the idea I have in mind is a transformation of a physical object into a two-dimensional projection of itself", and then the ghost thing is mentioned as a similar concept for which there is already a word. I agree you can't have a "physical ghost", but other than that example I think the OP really is thinking of physical objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will find a "real" word that encapsulates that concept; consider coining one; portrify, like used in the game, seems like a reasonable option.

there is a vaguely related idea in 'The Picture of Dorian Gray', where a magic  portrait ages instead of the protagonist